# CouchDB Memory Leak - Performance Issue

Tags: memory-leaks, erlang, couchdb, out-of-memory

I am experiencing performance issue with CouchDB.

Use Case: I am working on a process that retrieves the data from RDBMS and process them into JSON document and POST them to the CouchDB.

I am trying to POST around half a million documents, most of them in batches (_bulk_doc) of 10,000 and have tried with batch of 5,000, 15,000, and 20,000.

Whole process takes around 90-100 minutes.

During the life of the process, Memory Consumption by CouchDB keeps on growing and memory is not released when CouchDB has finished working.

So if the memory consumption by CouchDB was 60% at the time process finishes, memory consumption will remain 60% and not reducing.

Subsequently, when the process starts running again. memory consumption is Maxed out and CouchDB restarts itself. This restart fails the process that I am running. Looking at the Syslogs , I see Out Of Memory Error by the CouchDB process and killing statement.

The CouchDb process that has the issue is the "beam.smp" of Erlang.

At this point, I have tried upgrading the memory of the server to see if this resolves the issue, unfortunately, the issue persists. Memory Leak is there and Usage keeps on growing until CouchDB restarts/crashed.

I also have tried running garbage collection from Erlang command (erlang:garbage_collect().) line but it didn't do anything.

At this point, I am out of ideas and not sure what is going on here. Any input/suggestion is highly appreciated!

Env:
Platform: Linux (Red Hat release 6.4 (Santiago))
CouchDB: 1.3 and have tried with 1.5 as well
RAM: Tried with 2G, 4G, and 8G
CPU: 2 cores
Process:/usr/lib64/erlang/erts-5.8.5/bin/beam.smp -Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/lib64/erlang

Answer (score -1):

What kind of JSON parser are you using? Do you know that in Erlang atoms are not garbage collected? So if your parser is creating new atoms, they will stay forever, eventually consuming all your memory.

Comment: I am using Node.js to create and post the documents. And below is the Erlang memory snapshot when CouchDB stuck at consuming 44% of memory and not releasing it. erlang:memory([atom, atom_used, processes, processes_used, binary, code, ets]).
[
{atom,452089}
,
{atom_used,423359}
,
{processes,1112640}
,
{processes_used,1100560}
,
{binary,323400}
,
{code,3380827}
,
{ets,228416}
]

Comment: From erl manpage: Default number of atom is 1048576. You could try using command line parameter `+t` to increase the number, and see if the vm crash after parsing more documents. In that case I suspect there is something wrong with the parsers that parses your JSON documents.

Comment: Could you please post the command to do so, since I am not familiar with Erlang. How much memory I should assign  to Atom to do this test?

Comment: You could do something like: erl +t 2097152. But you have to search in couchdb start script where erl is started. Or where is appropriate to put additional parameters. This number is double of the default number of atoms, so you can do your math now ;)